# How to change the TableSection text color with a custom renderer - Xamarin.Forms C#

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.forms, custom-renderer

I have a `TableView` with 3 `TableSection`s in the root:

```
var tableView = new TableView
{
  RowHeight = 60,
  Root = new TableRoot
  {
    firstTableSection,
    secondTableSection,
    thirdTableSection,

  }
}

var firstTableSection = new TableSection("First")
{
  // Cells
}

var firstTableSection = new TableSection("First")
{
  // Cells
}

var firstTableSection = new TableSection("First")
{
  // Cells
}
```

How can you change the text color of the `TableSection` text with a custom renderer?

```
public class TestTableViewRenderer : Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.TableViewRenderer
{
    protected override void OnElementChanged(Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.ElementChangedEventArgs<Xamarin.Forms.TableView> e)
    {
        base.OnElementChanged(e);

        // Not sure how to add this property here

    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I wound up using this solution:

https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/32379/changing-the-title-color-of-a-tablesection

Which relies on two custom renderers:

```
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(TableView), typeof(CustomTableView))]
namespace APP.Droid
{
    public class CustomTableView : TableViewRenderer
    {
        protected override TableViewModelRenderer GetModelRenderer(global::Android.Widget.ListView listView, TableView view)
        {
            return new CustomTableViewModelRenderer(this.Context, listView, view);
        }

    }
}
```

and

```
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(TableViewModelRenderer), typeof(CustomTableViewModelRenderer))]
namespace APP.Droid
{
    public class CustomTableViewModelRenderer : TableViewModelRenderer
    {
        public CustomTableViewModelRenderer(Context Context, global::Android.Widget.ListView ListView, TableView View)
            : base(Context, ListView, View)
        { }
        public override global::Android.Views.View GetView(int position, global::Android.Views.View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
        {
            var view = base.GetView(position, convertView, parent);

            var element = this.GetCellForPosition(position);

            if (element.GetType() == typeof(TextCell))
            {
                try
                {
                    var text = ((((view as LinearLayout).GetChildAt(0) as LinearLayout).GetChildAt(1) as LinearLayout).GetChildAt(0) as TextView);
                    var divider = (view as LinearLayout).GetChildAt(1);

                    text.SetTextColor(Android.Graphics.Color.Rgb(50, 50, 50));
                    divider.SetBackgroundColor(Android.Graphics.Color.Rgb(150, 150, 150));
                }
                catch (Exception) { }
            }

            return view;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

might want to check out this thread on XF forum http://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/comment/189201/#Comment_189201